# Using jQuery to find the next div and show/hide it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm working on an application that lists products/sub products.  I'm trying to show the sub products when I click on the chevron.  For some reason, I can't get this to work.  I've been able to get the flipping of the chevron to work.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="item">
    Product 1
    <div style="float: right;"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-chevron-down" onclick="expand(this,event)"></i></div>

    <div class="sub-item-list" style="display: none">            
        <div class="sub-item">
            Sub Product 1
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>

function expand(event) {
    if ($(event).hasClass("fa-chevron-down")){
        setTimeout(function () {///workaround
            $(event).removeClass("fa-chevron-down");                
        }, 10);
                      
        $(event).addClass("fa-chevron-up"); 
        $(event).closest('div').next().find("sub-item-list").css('display', 'inherit');

    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {///workaround
            $(event).removeClass("fa-chevron-up");                
        }, 10);

        $(event).addClass("fa-chevron-down");
        $(event).closest('div').next().find("sub-item-list").css('display', 'none');
    }
};
```

Can someone tell me that the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are setting `onclick` event on `<i>` tag you can also call `parent().next()` method instead of `closest()` to get subitem/product.

**Try this example:**

```js
function expand(event)
{
    if ($(event).hasClass("fa-chevron-down"))
    {
        setTimeout(function() 
        {///workaround
            $(event).removeClass("fa-chevron-down");                
        }, 10);
                      
        $(event).addClass("fa-chevron-up"); 
        $(event).parent().next().css("display", "block");

    } 
    else 
    {
        setTimeout(function () 
        {///workaround
            $(event).removeClass("fa-chevron-up");                
        }, 10);
    
        $(event).addClass("fa-chevron-down");
        $(event).parent().next().css('display', 'none');
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
    Product 1
    <div style="float: right;">
        <i class="fas fa-fw fa-chevron-down" onclick="expand(this, event)">Toggle Chevron</i>
    </div>

    <div class="sub-item-list" style="display:none">            
        <div class="sub-item">
            Sub Product 1
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.closest('div.item')` to get the closest div and then use `.find(".sub-item-list")` to find the div which you need to display .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function expand(event) {
  if ($(event).hasClass("fa-chevron-down")) {
    setTimeout(function() { ///workaround
      $(event).removeClass("fa-chevron-down");
    }, 10);

    $(event).addClass("fa-chevron-up");
    //get closest div with class item -> find class
    $(event).closest('div.item').find(".sub-item-list").css('display', 'inherit');

  } else {
    setTimeout(function() { ///workaround
      $(event).removeClass("fa-chevron-up");
    }, 10);

    $(event).addClass("fa-chevron-down");
     //get closest div with class item -> find class
    $(event).closest('div.item').find(".sub-item-list").css('display', 'none');
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  Product 1
  <div style="float: right;"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-chevron-down" onclick="expand(this,event)"> >> </i></div>

  <div class="sub-item-list" style="display: none">
    <div class="sub-item">
      Sub Product 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a million!  I thought I was close.

Comment: @BrettDavis Your welcome .:) You can accept this answer if it works .